# How to fetch textbox value in .CS page(Testbox is inside a table) #Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to fetch the value of a `Textbox` which is inside a table. This table too is within a row of another column. I am trying to fetch it using `TextBox_UN.Text` (`nameofthetextbox.Text`) but it is throwing error saying this name doesn't exist. Please someone suggest me on this. I would really appreciate the help.
Thank you

```
LoginForm.aspx :

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>

     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="styleTable1">
          <tr>
             <td class="stylerow3">

                  <table align="center" 
                      style="border-left-style: outset; border-left-width: 3px; border-right: 3px outset #C0C0C0; border-top-style: outset; border-top-width: 3px; border-bottom: 3px outset #C0C0C0" >
                      <tr>
                         <td  style="color: #0066FF"></td>
                         <td >
                             <span style="font-size: xx-large; color: #0066CC; text-align: left;">LOGIN</span>
                         </td>
                         <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                         <td class="style1" style="color: #0066FF">Username</td>
                         <td class="style1">
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_UN" runat="server" Width="180px"> </asp:TextBox>
                         </td>
                         <td class="style1">
                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                         ControlToValidate="TextBox_UN" ErrorMessage="Please enter Username" 
                         ForeColor="#666666"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                         </td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                         <td class="style4" style="color: #0066FF">Password</td>
                         <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_PW" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="TextBox_PW" ErrorMessage="Please enter Password" 
                            ForeColor="#666666"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                         </td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                         <td ></td>
                         <td>
                           <asp:Button ID="B_Login" runat="server" onclick="B_Login_Click" Text="Submit" Width="78px" />
                         </td>
                         <td style="height: 30px"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
              </td>
         </tr>
     </table>

      </div>
    </form>
</body>




LoginForm.aspx.cs :

string checkuser = "select count(*) from Table1 where UserName='" + ***TextBox_UN.Text*** + "'";
```

Comment: Side note: search for "SQL injection" should give you working sample of what you are doing... Find, read and stop what you are doing. Parametrized queries rule them all.

Comment: page's class name and inherits address on top of the page must be the same,check this first

Comment: @ Nima   They are same

Answer (score 0):

Why DoNt you refer the object using its ID?
It doesn't matter where is the text box. The corresponding object is available on the code behind

Comment: @ Toji Thomas    I am using textbox's ID only to fetch this. But it is not working